# Creating a class with an Array of objects as read from an xml document

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to create a class called `Student` which contains the members name, GPA and an array of objects called `CourseRecord`. I'm completely lost here, since I can't use for or while loops in my class to initialize the `CourseRecord` objects. This is the code I would like to use, but I'm not able to use the for loop:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Register
{
    class StudentRecord
    {
        public string studentName;
        public double studentGPA;
        public CourseRecord[] grades = new CourseRecord[4];

        public StudentRecord()
        {
        }

        public StudentRecord(string name, double GPA)
        {
            studentName = name;
            studentGPA = GPA;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < CourseRecord.Length; i++;)
        {
        CourseRecord[i] = new CourseRecord;
        CourseRecord[i].Read;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: When you say you are not able to use a for loop, do you mean that the assignment has a rule saying you cannot use a for loop?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio is giving me the error "Invalid token 'for' in class, struct, or interface member declaration".

Comment: How does this relate to reading xml as you mention in your question title? It is completely unclear to me what you are trying to achieve or where you got stuck. "I'm completely lost here" is not a good question. Please refer to  [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and more specifically [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then [edit] your question and make it specifically about what you are trying to achieve, what approach you think you could follow and where you got stuck.

Comment: You mean you are having a compile error? Have you noticed that you are using int++ !

Comment: Also which method contains your `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this code is outside of a method body, which is causing the compiler error:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CourseRecord.Length; int++;)
{
    CourseRecord[i] = new CourseRecord;
    CourseRecord[i].Read;
}
```

Also, as a commenter said, you want `i++`, not `int++`;

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not inside of a method. Also, you should use `i++` and not `int++`, as it is the value of `i` you are increasing, not the value of `int`.

Also, I will assume that `CourseRecord.Read` is a method, in which case it should have parentheses after it in order to actually call the method.

```
public void ReadCourseRecords() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CourseRecord.Length; i++;)
    {
        CourseRecord[i] = new CourseRecord;
        CourseRecord[i].Read();
    }
}
```

If you add this method to your `StudentRecord` class, then when you call it, it should read the course records.